# ElasticBeanstalk environment URL points to old EC2 instance IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

For some reason I **manually terminated** the EC2 instance of my EB environment more than a week ago. A new instance started, and I thought it was all fine.

However, today, I see that my EB environment URL (*my-env-name.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com*) still **points to the old EC2 instance IP** when I ping it (it's not a DNS cache problem, I flushed it and tried with online ping services). And since the old instance doesn't exist anymore, I just can't reach my web application. I can reach it when I use the current EC2 instance public DNS though (*ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com*).

Is this behaviour expected or is it a bug? How can I make my environment URL to point to the current EC2 instance?

Comment: Hi GuiTeK, if the response below answered your question or helped with the resolution please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think *Elastic Beanstalk* is supposed to update the DNS name - you may want to investigate why it didn't. What if you change to deployment from not-LoadBalancer-based to LB-based and perhaps back again? Will it update the DNS name? Can you terminate the EC2 instance again and see if this time it gets updated? Is there something in the logs?

On the other hand if you have your own domain on *Route53* you can use that to resolve your EB deployment: [Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)

Comment: I tried both options, waited for hours, but nothing worked. I had to recreate the EB environment to make it work again.